# how to access js object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm lost on how to get object properties in JS. I'm getting values from firebase and I wanted to filter the result by its id:

```
//id is from query params (selecting 1 item from view)
const snippet = snippets.filter(snips => {
        if(snips.id == id) return snips;
})
```

If I console.log after these lines, I'm getting this:

[image]

```
const obj = snippet[0];
```

So I tried to get properties by using `snippet[0]` which returns this:

[image]

But if I try to get properties such as:

```
console.log(obj['id']);
//console.log(obj.title); - tried this as well
```

it returns:

[image]

Entering data:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You are likely running into an issue with async code. Also read up on how `Array#filter` is used properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how the array::filter function works. It iterates over the array and the callback returns a boolean true/false if the element should be returned in the result array.

```
const snippet = snippets.filter(snips => snips.id == id)
```

## Issue

> Cannot read property "title" of undefined

This is saying that `snippet[0]` is currently undefined when trying to access any properties

`snippet[0].title`, a root `title` property also doesn't exist in your other console log

## Solution

Your snippet is (*possibly*) an array of 1 (or 0) element, so in order to access the `title` nested in `data` property

```
snippet[0].data.title
```

And in the case that the array is empty or has an element without a `data` property, use optional chaining or guard clauses to check the access

```
snippet[0]?.data?.title
```

or

```
snippet[0] && snippet[0].data && snippet[0].data.title
```

Comment: got the same output.

Comment: @silent_coder14 When are you trying to access it in your code? Sometimes objects become "defined"/"populated" with data and properties by the time the console log is *actually* printed. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, i.e. the how and where the object access is used?

Comment: I think it works with this now: console.log(obj?.data?.title); Thank you!! It's just confusing because I'm getting the values initially but only to be lost after a while.

Answer (score 0):

looking at what you are asking you need to enter first the data.

console.log(obj[0].data.content)

Comment: can you please add more code so i can try it to in my editor. thx

Comment: thank you @Manuel, it seems working now: console.log(obj?.data?.title);